# blackberry.io.dir.appDirs is undefined

Tags: javascript, blackberry, config, blackberry-webworks

```
var dirs = blackberry.io.dir.appDirs;
alert(dirs);
```

prints "undefined"...

important parts of my config.xml:

```
<content src="http://10.0.0.117/MyApp/index.html"/>

<access uri="http://10.0.0.117" subdomains="true">
    <feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
    <feature id="blackberry.io.file" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
    <feature id="blackberry.io.dir" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
</access>

<rim:permissions>
    <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
</rim:permissions>

<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.io.file" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.io.dir" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

I found this [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/blackberry-io-dir-appDirs-not-working/td-p/1606225) that is pretty much the same problem, but also unsolved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you testing this on the Playbook?  appDirs is supported on the Playbook, not on the hand helds.

Thanks

Naveen M

Comment: i tested it on smartphones, not on the tablet, thank you, i didn't read the supported platforms for this property, i only checked the supported platforms table for blackberry.io.dir